# Another Regex Issue

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with lines like:

```
2015-08-11 13:31:06.609 CEST [SwitchEvent Thread] INFO  o.o.t.t.internal.learning.Learning - Probabilities for Host 1:  [Switch 1: 1.0]
2015-08-11 13:31:07.349 CEST [SwitchEvent Thread] INFO  o.o.t.t.internal.learning.Learning - Probabilities for Host 1:  [Switch 1: 0.5, Switch 2: 0.5]
```

And I want to get the last part of it (e.g. in line 1, I want to get `[Switch 1: 1.0]`)

For that, I have this pattern: `(\[Switch .*\])`.
And this is (a part of) the code I am using:

```
import os
import sys
import re

data_pattern = re.compile('(\[Switch .*\])')

f = open('some_file', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
    data_match = data_pattern.match(line)
    print data_match.group(0)
```

The whole thing results in a crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nemo-develop/PycharmProjects/Affinity-Remote/learning_data_preparation.py", line 62, in <module>
    read_file(join(directory, filename), switch_amount)
  File "/home/nemo-develop/PycharmProjects/Affinity-Remote/learning_data_preparation.py", line 33, in read_file
    print data_match.group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
2015-08-11 13:31:06.609 CEST [SwitchEvent Thread] INFO  o.o.t.t.internal.learning.Learning - Probabilities for Host 1:  [Switch 1: 1.0]
```

So the line is not matched.
I also checked on regex101. It seems to work there.. [Here is a link to it](https://www.regex101.com/r/hB2fN4/1).

What is going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong with the regex, just tried it on my side. I'm not at home in python.

Comment: When I used `findall` with your regex I got `['[Switch 1: 1.0]', '[Switch 1: 0.5, Switch 2: 0.5]']` so it seems to match fine for me

Comment: `match` matches when the pattern is found at the beginning of the string. Use `search` or, as suggested below, `findall` if all of the data is in a single string.

Comment: [Use `re.compile(r'(\[Switch .*\])')` and `re.search`](http://ideone.com/dqAsr2).

Comment: You need to use search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pattern is not at the beginning of the line, you need to use search, match will fail unless the pattern is at the beginning of the line:

```
import re
data_pattern = re.compile(r'(\[Switch .*\])')

f = open('some_file', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
    # CHANGE TO RE.SEARCH HERE:
    data_match = data_pattern.search(line)
    print data_match.group(0)
```